# Allow Origin and Allow-Headers is that not allow a hacker to come in?

Tags: jquery, .htaccess, cordova

We are developing a jQuery mobile app with phonegap and we are asked to add the below 2 lines in .htaccess.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
```

I am not an expert on .htaccess but I understand that is for security purposes.  Will the above code doesn't open any path for a hacker to come in?

Answer (score 1):

That's only a problem when you are testing the html file of the app. Once you are sure that your html file is okay just run it over your phone or emulator. You would not face any problems over there. The "Origin" problem gets automatically solved when it becomes an app.